# Verificar se registros existem com Python

Tags: mysql, sql, python, if, else

Fala galera estou indo do SQL para o python e ainda estou meio confus. É o seguinte aqui no meu código eu quero saber se os valores do select da variável result existem no select da variável venda, e se existirem não faça nada, e se não existirem carregue os dados. No sql eu usava o If exists, não sei qual é o equivalente no python. Desde já Agradeço.

> Exemplo eu estou trazendo registro de uma tabela do sql e carregando
>   em outra tabela do Mysql, ai no caso de já tiver esses registro na
>   tabela do mysql quero que imprima na tela: não possui novos registro,
>   e no caso de ter registro que ainda não estão na tabela do Mysql quero
>   que carregue os esses registros.
>
> Obs: jogo os dados no dataframe para depois carregar no mysql

import pymysql.cursors
    import pyodbc
    import pandas as pd
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine

```
connection = pyodbc.connect("DSN=SQLServer")  #autocommit=True

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        result = "SELECT * FROM dw.dbo.vW_vendas"
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM dw.dbo.vW_Vendas",connection,index_col=None,coerce_float=True, parse_dates= 'DataBaseContrato')
        cursor.execute(result)
        table = cursor.fetchall()
        print(table)             

finally:
    connection.close()

#Conexão Mysql
cnx = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://teste:teste@teste/dw')
cnxmysql = pymysql.connect(host='teste',
                             user='teste',
                             password='teste',
                             db='dw')
try:
    with cnxmysql.cursor() as cursor2:
        venda = "SELECT * FROM ft_venda_teste"
        cursor2.execute(venda)
        venda = cursor2.fetchall()
        print(venda)
finally:
    cnxmysql.close()

df.to_sql(con=cnx, name= 'ft_venda_teste',if_exists= 'replace', index= False)
print('dados Carregados')
```

Comment: Ficou meio confuso, vc quer verificar se registros existem na tabela no momento do select?

Comment: Isso mesmo, Exemplo eu estou trazendo registro de uma tabela do sql e carregando em outra tabela do Mysql, ai no caso de já tiver esses registro na tabela do mysql quero que imprima na tela: não possui novos registro, e no caso de ter registro que ainda não estão na tabela do Mysql quero que carregue os esses registros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu nao consegui entender muito bem o requisito, mas parece que voce quer sincronizar vendas de um DW no SQL Server com um outro banco no MySQL.

Eu nao consegui testar a solucao abaixo, pois nao possuo um ambiente configurado para rodar SQL Server e MySQL, mas tente entender a logica abaixo:

```
import pymysql.cursors
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


def get_vendas_sqlserver():
    connection = pyodbc.connect("DSN=SQLServer")  #autocommit=True

    try:
        # Vc nao precisa de um cursor e o read_sql_query do pandas aqui
        # O metodo do pandas ja vai retornar o resultado do seu select
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM dw.dbo.vW_Vendas",connection,index_col=None,coerce_float=True, parse_dates= 'DataBaseContrato')

        return df
    finally:
        connection.close()

def get_vendas_mysql()
    #Conexão Mysql
    cnxmysql = pymysql.connect(host='teste',
                                 user='teste',
                                 password='teste',
                                 db='dw')
    try:
        # mesmo acima
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM ft_venda_teste", cnxmysql, index_col=None, coerce_float=True,
                               parse_dates='DataBaseContrato')

        return df
    finally:
        cnxmysql.close()

def merge_vendas():
    df1 = get_vendas_sqlserver()
    df2 = get_vendas_mysql()
    #cria um dataframe vazio para guardar o resultado
    df_result = pd.DataFrame()

    # o metodo iterrows retorna um tuple com o indice (numero da linha) e Pd.Series com o "registro" em si
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        # verifica se este registro existe no DF do MySQL
        if row["vendaid"] in df2["vendaid"]:
            print("Venda {0} encontrada no SQL Server".format(row["vendaid"]))
        else:
            print("Venda {0} nao encontrada no SQL Server".format(row["vendaid"]))
            # adiciona o registro num novo DF que vai ser usado para gravar no banco adiante
            df_result.append(row)

    write_results(df_result)

def write_results(df_result):
    cnx = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://teste:teste@teste/dw')

    df_result.to_sql(con=cnx, name='ft_venda_teste', if_exists='append', index=False)
    print('dados Carregados')
```

Talvez essa nao seja a maneira mais "elegante" de atingir o que vc esta precisando, mas eu quis aproveitar o seu raciocinio para vc conseguir seguir minha logica.

Espero que seja um ponto de partida!

Comment: dessa forma ele me retornou um erro '>' not supported between instances of 'pyodbc.Cursor' and 'int

Comment: Seu codigo esta um pouco confuso, da pra criar umas tres funcoes:
getVendasSQL e getVendasMySQL (nomes so sao sugestao, eu nao entendo do negocio). Depois disso, acho que vc pode fazer com que os dois selecionem os dados e uma terceira funcao compararia pra criar o diff. Tbm notei que isso nao produz o resultado que vc espera `df.to_sql(con=cnx, name= 'ft_venda_teste',if_exists= 'replace', index= False)`. Veja que o `if_exists='replace'` na verdade [dropa a tabela e recria do zero](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). Append talvez?

Comment: estou iniciando agora no python então ainda estou apanhando

Comment: Eu vou reformular minha resposta pra algo mais proximo do que voce precisa.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela força Iann

Comment: Obrigado Iann sua resposta ajudou muito

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro é preciso identificar que o resultado da variável *result* está na verdade na variável *table*, como você mesmo usa no *print()* do primeiro *catch*.

Sabendo disso, você pode criar um set() pra cada lista de resultados, isso eliminará os elementos repetidos de cada lista de resultados e permitirá interação entre as coleções (Podendo por exemplo, criar uma nova lista com o resultado):

```
x = set(table)
print(x)
>>> {resultado1, resultado2, resultado3, resultado4}

y = set(venda)
print(y)
>>> {resultado1, resultado2, resultado3, resultado5}

z = list(x - y)
print(z)
>>> [resultado4]
```

Entretanto, se precisar dos valores repetidos, pode usar um *for loop*, com um *if not in*, que identifica se o elemento **não** está contido numa lista:

```
z = list()
for i in venda:
    if i not in table
    z.append(i)
```

E então os resultados estarão na lista z.

> **Edit:**

Conforme mencionado pelo @ytalo-matos-bandeira-da-silva, pra usar *lists* com *set()*, é preciso transformá-las primeiro em *tuples*:

```
x = set(tuple(table))
print(x)
>>> {resultado1, resultado2, resultado3, resultado4}

y = set(tuple(venda))
print(y)
>>> {resultado1, resultado2, resultado3, resultado5}

z = list(x - y)
print(z)
>>> [resultado4]
```

Comment: Quando eu crio o set ele me retorna um erro unhashable type: 'pyodbc.Row'

Comment: Isso é porque o set não permite criar coleção com *alteráveis* como *list()* ou *dict()*, mas com tuple() é possível, então transforme primeiro seus resultados em tuplas, vou alterar a resposta pra maior esclarecimento.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda,vou tentar agora

Comment: Mesmo transformando as list ocorreu o mesmo erro

Comment: Sei que já resolveu seu problema mas só por questões de registro pra usuários futuros, você poderia comentar com o erro completo? Ou pelo menos um pouco mais completo pra identificar o motivo?

Comment: sim, mesmo quando eu transformo em tupla ele continua me retornando o erro unhashable type: 'pyodbc.Row',   e não deixa eu criar a coleção

Answer (score -2):

Complementando a resposta do Iann:

```
rows = cursor.execute(result)
if rows > 0:
    table = cursor.fetchall()
    // Eu colocaria o resultado no df, aqui 
else:
     // Trate aqui o "vazio"
```

Comment: Gostaria de enteder o STOpt, vc tenta complementar uma resposta e ganha um downvote. Acho que por esse motivo esta caindo muito a qualidade aqui e espantando tantos usuarios. Lamentável.